# Error "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the **Exception** in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` Error. **Eclipse says** to me that it is in this statement of code

```
            myArray[i][j] = tmpDouble;
```

but I dont know why.

Code:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int N;
    private double[][] myArray = new double[N][N];
    private ArrayList<anObject> myList;

    public MyClass(ArrayList<anObject> aList){

        myList = new ArrayList<anObject>();
        myList = aList;

        HashSet<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();

        String[] anArray = uniqueSet.toArray(new String[uniqueSet.size()]);
        N = uniqueSet.size();
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for (int ii=0;ii<N;ii++){
                myArray[i][ii] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            //if (i==j)myArray[i][j]=0;
            for(anObject s : myList){
                if (s.getName1().equals(arrayNameOfHashSet[i])){
                    tmpDouble = Math.abs(s.getScore1()-s.getScore2());
                    tmpString = s.getName2();
                    for (j=0;j<N;j++){
                        if (s.getName2().equals(arrayNameOfHashSet[i])){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }   

            myArray[i][j] = tmpDouble;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is that `j` coming from...? Your inner loop uses `ii` as counter.

Comment: the code you have shown here will not compile as "j" is not declared, also N will be zero when you create a new double array[0][0]

Comment: syntax error while I wrote the code in stackoverflow.  I have the same problem with  (ii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `myArray` has size 0.
You need to initialize it again:

```
N = uniqueSet.size();
myArray = new double[N][N];
```

Comment: Check the update please, Can u image why I have the same error with that updated code ?

Comment: The same reason, you initialized your array only with `N = 0` from `private int N;` in the beginning. Then you try to set value to any element in the array though the size is still 0. In the 1st case where `N = uniqueSet.size();` you have `N = 0` again because of empty `HashSet` and you miss a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
 HashSet<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();

   private int N= uniqueSet.size(); // assign some value to N
    private double[][] myArray = new double[N][N];
```